# Order of $ and ^ in vim. Is it reversed?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

In vi `^` moves cursor leftmost (to first nonwhite character) and `$` moves cursor rightmost in line. `^` `$` are right to left on my keyboard (that is `$` `^`), which means key on left (`$`) moves cursor rightmost and key on right (`^`) moves cursor leftmost.

I found it confusing, I would expect the keys to be other way.

Is  that order just a coincidence or is there any reason for it? Thanks.

Comment: hey, on [my layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#French), it is not reversed :)

Comment: It's a case of computers imitating life.  In life you are First offered the Carrot, then when you get to the End you get the Dollars.

Answer (score 9):

In [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), `^` is a special anchor character meaning "start of line" and `$` is a special anchor character meaning "end of line".  I don't know if there's any special reason those were chosen.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the usage of `^` for "start of a line" originates from the old [ADM-3A terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM-3A) (c. 1975), whose keyboard layout is shown below (taken from the Wikipedia article). The `^` symbol is the same key as `Home` and `~`, which is also why `~` is used for the home directory in Unix. This layout is also the origin of `hjkl` as movement keys in Vi(m).

[image]

I don't know why `$` was originally used for "end of line", but maybe it is simply because it resembles a letter `S`, and so was chosen for string termination. The `$` was also used to delimit "[formatted transput](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALGOL_68#formatted_transput)" in ALGOL 68 (c. 1968), so maybe there are more ancient origins.

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this is related as PCDOS postdates Unix, as the original PCDOS assembler used the '$' char to terminate strings. c.f. stackoverflow.com/questions/481344/dollar-terminated-strings. I am note sure where PCDOS got this inspiration from.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in regex `^` indicates beginning of the line and `$` the end of it. Once you've done enough regex maches it seems natural ;)

Answer (score 2):

I expect it relates to the meaning of `^` (start of line) and `$` (end of line) within regular expressions.

Comment: Care to share what you do use instead? `0` and `E` come to mind, though they do different things

Comment: Actually I do use those keys and always have done - I was getting confusion.